# Silverlight identifyTask w/fieldsToDisplay not showing multi features

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, arcgis

I am attempting to create an ComboBox which is populated from an IdentifyTask (the task comes from the ArcGIS Silverlight API). I am having issues with two events. One creates a list while the other pushes that list out to the ComboBox. I cannot seem to create the list properly. Right now, the ComboBox is only blank.

**Here is a XAML snippet:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="IdentifyComboBox" SelectionChanged="cb_SelectionChanged"
                     Margin="5,1,5,5" Grid.Row="0">
                </ComboBox>
```

**Here is a C# snippet:**

```
public void ShowFeatures(List<IdentifyResult> results)
        {
            _dataItems = new List<DataItem>();

            if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
            {
                var fieldsToDisplay = new List<string>() { "OBJECTID", "Projekt", "Laufzeit", "Ansprechpa" };
                foreach (IdentifyResult result in results)
                {
                    Graphic feature = result.Feature;
                    string title = result.Value.ToString() + " (" + result.LayerName + ")";
                    var attributesToDisplay = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (var item in feature.Attributes)
                        if (fieldsToDisplay.Contains(item.Key))
                            attributesToDisplay[item.Key] = item.Value;

                    _dataItems.Add(new DataItem()
                    {
                        Title = title,
                        Data = attributesToDisplay
                    });
                }
                IdentifyComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        void cb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = IdentifyComboBox.SelectedIndex;
            if (index > -1)
                IdentifyDetailsDataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataItems[index].Data;
        }
```

Comment: A lot of info is left out here. What does the  _dataItems collection hold. What is 'Data' What does ShowFeatures do, the list goes on and on

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Thanks for noting the issues. I thought I had included the event which creates 'Data'. I have now edited the post. Hopefully it is more descriptive of the issue I am having.

Comment: I'm guessing that _dataItems is suppose to be what populates the ComboBox, but you are not setting the ItemsSource of the ComboBox